# Getting page number from a Word document

Tags: c++, interop, ms-word, managed

I want to create an index page for which I need the page number from the Word document. I am working with C++ managed code and Word interop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx) for info on this.  This is for C#, but the classes are all available in C++/CLI.

There is page number info info here for including page numbers in a footer, and also on handling Table of Contents.